# R, generating dataframe row from factor values

Tags: r

I have an R data frame with factor columns.

```
dataframe <- read.csv("import.csv")
dataframe$col1 = as.factor(dataframe$col1)
dataframe$col2 = as.factor(dataframe$col2)
...
```

How can I generate a new row from labels?

```
newRow = dataframe[1,] #template
newRow[1] = ?
newRow[2] = ?
```

Lets say `col1` includes `"TestValue"`. I would like to set `newRow[1]` value to `"TestValue"` as if it was selected from my `dataframe`. How can I do that?

I know I can get factor index like so:

```
match(c("TestValue"),levels(dataframe$col1))
[1] 3
```

But whenever I assign anything to `newRow[1]`, I seem to change its type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a `factor` to `newRow[1]` and maintain the levels too.

In your case:

```
newRow[1] <- factor('TestValue', levels = levels(df$col1))
```

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters, b = letters)
new <- df[1, ]

new[1] <- factor('b', levels = levels(df[[1]]))
```

Output:

```
> str(new)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 2
 $ b: Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1
```

column a is still a factor with all the levels